# Store preprocessed data for later use via PyCharm

Tags: machine-learning, keras, pycharm, save

After generating data for a machine learning algorithm using Keras, how do you save the LabelEncoder data?

The data is generated via the code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.utils import to_categorical

# Convert features and corresponding classification labels into numpy arrays
X = np.array(featuresdf.feature.tolist())
y = np.array(featuresdf.class_label.tolist())

# Encode the classification labels
le = LabelEncoder()
yy = to_categorical(le.fit_transform(y))

# split the dataset
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, yy, test_size=0.2, random_state = 42)
```

From using Jupyter Notebook, one can save the data via:

```
### store the preprocessed data for use in the next notebook

%store x_train
%store x_test
%store y_train
%store y_test
%store yy
%store le
```

In PyCharm,  I can successfully save the `x_train` data via:

```
savetxt(x_train.csv, x_train, delimiter=',')
```

However, this method does not work for the `LabelEncoder`.

I then tried using `pickle` via the code:

```
pickle.dump(le, open(filename, 'wb')
```

to save the encoded data.  However, when I went to recall the data via:

```
LabelEnc = open(filename, 'rb')
le = pickle.load(LabelEnc)
```

I get the error: `...ValueError("Cannot load file containing pickled data " ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False`.

How can I correctly save and recall the `le` data?

This is a snippet of the data in PyCharm's "Show Variables" window:

[image]

Comment: `le` variable is reference to LabelEncoder() is just a instance of class and doesn't contain any data.

Comment: can you show your full code, because pickle dont give such error, either you are saving file in a wrong way or you might have updated the pickle keyword.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa.  Thanks for your response!  I have added a screen capture of the data from PyCharm's "Show Variables" window. How can I use the data in `le` or the `LabelEncoder()` at a later time?

Comment: You can just call `new_le = LabelEncoder()`; as you dont have any specific data associated with it.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa, there is data associated.  As shown in the snippet of PyCharm's window, `le` has the `classes_={ndarray: (10,)} ['air _conditioner' 'car_horn' ....`

Comment: Are you sure that you're using pickle-save and load, and not really numpy.load(), this problem is quite common on numpy load()

Comment: Also, just change the file read and write to 'r', and 'w' instead of 'rb' n 'wb'